# WPF: binding seletion of text to sliders?

Tags: wpf, data-binding

In a [WPF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Presentation_Foundation) based project I would like to bind the content of a TextBox to two sliders in such a way that first slider would start selection (from left or right based on a checkbox) from the
n-th character (n being slider value) to the m-th character (based on second slider value).
In essence I would like to specify selection range based on slider values.

How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally, you would bind TextBox.[SelectionStart](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textbox.selectionstart.aspx) and TextBox.[SelectionLength](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textbox.selectionlength.aspx) to values from the slider. (Probably via a converter that implements [IMultiValueConverer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.imultivalueconverter.aspx))

Unfortunately, you can't, because you can only bind Dependency Properties, and SelectionStart and SelectionLength are not dependency properties.

To solve this problem you would have to handle the [OnValueChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.slider.onvaluechanged.aspx) event on the sliders, then update the SelectionStart and SelectionLength properties via code in the event handler.

Disappointing answer - I bet you were hoping for some slick XAML code :-)

Comment: Yeah, that would be ideal but that other solution doesn't sound that hard. Thanks :)